# Storing values from delegates

Tags: c#, delegates, multicast

if I have a delegate and then I add a couple of methods to it how do I store each returned value separate?

say for example I had something like below, what do I do to have both values from both methods so I can display them in the PlayWithDelegate method, do I just set up a static array and store the results there or is there some other way?

```
public delegate string EnterName();

internal class Class1
{
    //Our delegate
    public delegate string EnterName();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EnterName testname = Getname;
        testname += GetAge;
        PlayWithDelegate(testname());
    }

    private static string GetAge()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age : ");
        string result = Console.ReadLine();
        if (result == "") result = " a mystery";
        return result;
    }

    private static void PlayWithDelegate(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "your name is {0} and age is {1}",name, name );
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static string Getname( )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name : ");
        string result = Console.ReadLine();
        if (result == "") result = " a mystery";
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store them as separate values. I made a slight modification to your solution.

In your code, you are re-assigning the function delegate to another, and so it replaces the previous value. This is why the results only end up showing the age instead of both name and age.

In the modified code, i ensure that I keep both delegates assigned to the functions and keep them seperate, then I call those delegates within the `PlayWithDelegate` function.

```cs
public delegate string UserInput();

internal class Class1
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserInput name = Getname;
        UserInput age = GetAge;
        PlayWithDelegate(name, age);
    }

    private static string GetAge()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age : ");
        string result = Console.ReadLine();
        if (result == "") result = " a mystery";
        return result;
    }

    private static void PlayWithDelegate(UserInput name, UserInput age)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("your name is {0} and age is {1}", name(), age());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static string Getname()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name : ");
        string result = Console.ReadLine();
        if (result == "") result = " a mystery";
        return result;
    }
}
```

You also mentioned potentially storing results into a collection of some kind, you could also do that...

```cs
public delegate string UserInput();

internal class Class1
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserInput[] inputs = new UserInput[] { Getname, GetAge };       
        string[] results = inputs.Select(func => func()).ToArray();     
        PlayWithDelegate(results);
    }

    private static string GetAge()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age : ");
        string result = Console.ReadLine();
        if (result == "") result = " a mystery";
        return result;
    }

    private static void PlayWithDelegate(string[] results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("your name is {0} and age is {1}", results[0], results[1]);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static string Getname()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name : ");
        string result = Console.ReadLine();
        if (result == "") result = " a mystery";
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that is great, I was under the impression the testname += GetAge; would add another function and not replace it so kind of chaining functions together, meaning I would only need to call my method with one parameter that had multiple functions connected to it in a chain unlike doing what you have done and call many parameters each one for a different function based of the delegate, perhaps I was wrong; this is purely just out of curiosity anyway and I appreciate you taking the time